# How do I filter reocurring numbers within a code block in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

In Notepad++ I have a document with all sorts of things but one line keeps reoccurring:

```
<ID>6354654</ID>
<ID>4252352</ID>
```

(notice how the numbers within the code block are different)

I'm trying to filter out these "ID" code blocks from the rest of the code, including the random numbers inside them.

Bonus question:
Does anyone know whether it would be possible to ONLY filter out the numbers within the ID code block?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my first question:

The answer is to use the following when searching:

```
<ID>(.|\n)*?<\/ID>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to search, check the "regular expression" checkbox.
then find what: `^<ID>.*`

Comment: that gave me an error: "Find: Can't find the text "^<ID>.*"
(with regular expression turned on)